# generating multiple files to pdf in for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying to generate multiple files to pdf using **"html-pdf-node"** package in for loop. But the problem is that after generating some files it give **Protocol error (Page.printToPDF): Target closed**. I have use promise.all() but could not solve the issue. Any help will be appreciated. thanks

below is my code

```
for (let index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
        const file_name = getRandomFileName();
        const html="abc";

        const margin = {
          top: "210px",
          right: "100px",
          bottom: "150px",
          left: "80px",
        };

        const options = {
          format: "A4",
          path: `some/path/{file_name}.pdf`,
          margin: margin,
        };

        const file = await html_to_pdf
          .generatePdf({ content: html }, options)
          .then(async (pdfBuffer) => {
            await fs.writeFileSync(options.path, pdfBuffer);
            filename.push(file_name);

            console.log("PDF saved successfully!");
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error generating PDF:", error);
          });
      }
return filename
}
```

I have searched and find a relative solution to use Promise.all . I have updated my code with using promise.all() but it did not work.

below is the code I tried

```
const file = await **Promise.all**(html_to_pdf
          .generatePdf({ content: html }, options)
          .then(async (pdfBuffer) => {
            await fs.writeFileSync(options.path, pdfBuffer);
            filename.push(file_name);

            console.log("PDF saved successfully!");
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error generating PDF:", error);
          })
)
```

Comment: Why are you using both `await` and `.then()` on the promise? It doesn't make sense to me.